# Running more than one command at a new shell (blocking)

Tags: android, ruby

I need to run several commands on an adb shell.

My first attempt was to use popen:

```
def adb_root(commands) 
   console = IO.popen('adb shell', :mode => 'w') 
   commands.each do |cmd|
     console.puts(cmd)
   end
end
```

But this starts a sub process and I don't know when all commands are executed.
I would need this to be blocking.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use "bash -c" instead of "adb shell"

```
commands_array = ["ls /", "cd /tmp/", "echo 123"]

def run_commands(commands)
    response = []
    commands.each do |command|
        IO.popen("/bin/bash -c #{command}") do | cmd_io |
            response << cmd_io.readlines.map(&:strip) 
            puts "Response:  #{response.inspect}"
        end
    end
    return response
end

puts run_commands(commands_array).inspect
```

This opens a new (bash/adb) shell for each command. There isn't a really good way to know when the command is finished otherwise as far as I know. Hope this helps.